# "Error with Permissions-Policy header: Unrecognized feature: 'ch-ua-form-factor'" and site loading very slow

Tags: iframe, console, http-permissions-policy

Browser: Google Chrome. I'm getting this warning on a php site with 14 YouTube embedded videos, and I have noticed that since this error showing up (it's new as far as I know) the site is taking longer to load... Around 20-25 seconds total.

The warning is piled up a few thousand times, varying each time I reload the page, like you can see here:

[image]

An example of how I embed the videos, it's exactly how YouTube dictates but I prefer to show all the info just in case:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/XXXXXXX" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I have read in another posts here that the warning can just be ignored, but I find a bit bizarre to see it piled up so many times. Also, I don't know if this is relevant, but my site is not made with React or any other framework as it was in the other cases I have read about this error, just php and vanilla js (+ jQuery). Could anyone elaborate on why is it okay to just ignore the warning or if it may have something to do with the fact that sites take longer to load? Thank you!